# Draw horizontal stroke on text flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to draw horizontal strokes around a `Text` with flutter like the one I show below?

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuQFY.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a single line through text with in style in Text widget

```
   Text('N',style: TextStyle(fontSize:30,decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                decorationThickness: 2.85,),)
```

if you want to double strike,but you can create a image of line then show that into a Text Widget you can check the following link or you can use the below answer by savke

[custom-strikethrough-to-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56141301/how-to-add-custom-strikethrough-to-text-widget-in-flutter/56145366)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Stack widget.

```
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'N',
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 8,
              child: Container(
              width: 10,
              height: 2,
              color: Colors.grey
            ),
           ),
            Positioned(
              top: 12,
              child: Container(
              width: 10,
              height: 2,
              color: Colors.grey
            ),
           ),
          ],
        ),
```

And Stack widget you can put in some Container to limit size of widget.